# Change Type and Value Input with angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, angular8

Im started to work in isolate angular 8 library, and I want to create a input component with some caracteristics, the trouble is when i set type propertie in input the value propertie do not show anything, its a example with the type Date and value **new Date('12-23-2009')**

```js
interface ITypeInput {
  getType: ()=>string
  getValue:()=>any
}

abstract class ATypeInput {
  value: any;
  constructor(value: any) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  setValue(val: any) {
    this.value = val;
  }

  getValue() {
    return this.value;
  }
}

export class TextTypeInput extends ATypeInput implements ITypeInput  {
  getType = ()=>'text';
}

export class NumberTypeInput extends ATypeInput implements ITypeInput  {
  getType = ()=>'number';
}

export class DateTypeInput extends ATypeInput implements ITypeInput {
  getType = ()=>'date';
}

export class KInputComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() inputData: ITypeInput;
  @Output() changeValue: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  type: string;
  value: any;
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if(!!changes.inputData) {
      this.type = this.getTypeOf(changes.inputData.currentValue)
      this.value = changes.inputData.currentValue.getValue()
    }
  }
  constructor() { }

  getTypeOf(currentValue:ITypeInput): string {
    return currentValue.getType();
  }

  valueInputChange(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.changeValue.emit(value);
  }
}



///app-component

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angul-akita';
  initialValue:any;
  constructor(){
    this.initialValue =new DateTypeInput(new Date('12-23-2009'));
  }
}
```

```html
//KInputComponent
<input [value]="value" [type]="type"/>

//appComponent
<k-input [inputData]="initialValue"> </k-input>
```

app comoponent only update type in Input componet but the value do not show.

some idea why is happen?

[image]